# Writing FusionChart objects from parent window to child window

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fusioncharts

So I have a problem. As most of us do when asking a question.

Our site is supposed to work universally pretty much in IE and ideally in at least Chrome as well. Currently Chrome can be damned as IE is proving uncooperative (big surprise eh?).

I've been tasked with making one of our reports that utilizes a mix of Telerik RadGrids and Fusion Charts graphs in a very specific way. This process has involved having to copy my report div (ReportDataContainer in the below code) to a child window.

In non-compat/edge mode, its working fine. Main report loads. Click the print button, pop, up comes the new window. Write the ReportDataContainer content to the new window along with a JS handler for the Fusion Charts render method and once both are rendered - invoke print.

In compat mode however the graph never loads on the new window though. No idea why not - it renders fine on the original report.

Anyway some code.

This is the JS I'm using to pop the new window, write to it and print: -

```
    function PrintDrill() {
    var cssArray = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
    var css = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cssArray.length; i++) {
        css += "<style type='text/css'>" + cssArray[i].innerHTML + "</style>";
    }
    drill = window.open();
    drill.document.write("<html>" +
        "<head>" + css +
        "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" />" +
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "function FC_Rendered(DOMId) { $(\"#\" + DOMId.split(\"_\")[0] + \"Loaded\").val('true'); } " +
        "<\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='/CTWebScripts/Libraries/jquery-1.5.min.js'><\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='/CTWebScripts/Libraries/jquery.color.js'><\/script>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='divActualYearGraphLoaded' name='actualYearGraphLoaded' value='false' />" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='divParcGraphLoaded' name='parcGraphLoaded' value='false' />" +
        $("#ReportDataContainer").html() +
        "</body>");

    drill.document.close();

    setTimeout(finishedRendering, 2000);
}

var drill = null;

function finishedRendering() {
    var loadedActualYear = $('#divActualYearGraphLoaded', drill.document).val();
    var loadedParc = $('#divParcGraphLoaded', drill.document).val();
    if (loadedActualYear == 'true' && loadedParc == 'true') {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0)
            drill.location.reload();
        setTimeout(printMyChild, 3000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(finishedRendering, 1000);
    }
}

function printMyChild() {
    drill.print();
}
```

And for comparison heres the two ways the FusionChart renders, first edge (the one that works): -

```
<div id="divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv">
<object width="100%" height="430" class="FusionCharts" id="divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDiv" data="/CTWebCharts/V3/StackedColumn3DLine.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" lang="EN" style="visibility: visible;">
    <param name="scaleMode" value="noScale">
    <param name="scale" value="noScale">
    <param name="wMode" value="opaque">
    <param name="bgColor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="quality" value="best">
    <param name="flashvars" value="*snip*">
</object>
```

And secondly compat mode - aka the one that DOESN'T work (on the new window anyway :/ ): -

```
<DIV id=divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv>
<OBJECT lang=EN id=divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDiv class=FusionCharts style="VISIBILITY: visible" classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000 width="100%" height=430>
    <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="10081">
    <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="11377">
    <PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="*snip*">
    <PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="/CTWebCharts/V3/StackedColumn3DLine.swf">
    <PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="/CTWebCharts/V3/StackedColumn3DLine.swf">
    <PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Opaque">
    <PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High">
    <PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE="LT">
    <PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="always">
    <PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="NoScale">
    <PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE="FFFFFF">
    <PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreenInteractive" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM NAME="IsDependent" VALUE="0">
</OBJECT>
```

So yea - the renderings pretty darn different. Just changing the new window over to being edge instead? Doesn't work. Forcing the main report into edge first also causes all hell to break loose. Not an option.

I've tried copying to an iframe to print from instead. Same issue.

Posted on the FusionCharts forum as well albeit in a slightly more disjointed manner.

Anyway. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I came up with a solution in the end. Not technically ideal considering FusionCharts were like "OMG, you on an old version! Upgrade!" but unfortunately that solution was outside my authority to action.

The first big change? The child document had to do pretty much ALL the work.

Secondly, instead of relying on simply copying the chart object and hoping it'll work I stored the chart XML produced to render the reports on the parent page after it was created to then pass into the child and re-render after very specifically setting the rendered to be the javascript renderer.

One note on this if you follow in my footsteps - careful when you store it. Being XML if you store it in a HiddenField or some such it IS going to give you grief most likely. So remember to make it HTML safe then re-parse it to its original values before pulling it out and rendering it again.

So in-case anyone was interested or simply wants to tell me what an awful hack this is - here's the resulting code: -

```
function UndoSafeForHTML(s) {
    s = ReplaceAll(s, "\\'", "'");
    s = ReplaceAll(s, "&lt;", "<");
    s = ReplaceAll(s, "&gt;", ">");
    return ReplaceAll(s, "<br>", "\n");
}

function ReplaceAll(s, find, replace) {
    return s.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

function PrintDrill() {
    var cssArray = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
    var css = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cssArray.length; i++) {
        css += "<style type='text/css'>" + cssArray[i].innerHTML + "</style>";
    }
    var parcXml = document.getElementById('<%# hdnParcChartXml.ClientID %>').value;
    var actualXml = document.getElementById('<%# hdnActualChartXml.ClientID %>').value;

    parcXml = UndoSafeForHTML(parcXml);
    actualXml = UndoSafeForHTML(actualXml);

    drill = window.open();
    drill.document.write("<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        css +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='/CTWebScripts/General.js'><\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/CTWebCharts/v3/swfobject.js\"><\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/CTWebCharts/V3/FusionCharts.js\"><\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='/CTWebScripts/Libraries/jquery-1.5.min.js'><\/script>" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='/CTWebScripts/Libraries/jquery.color.js'><\/script>" +
        "<script type='text/javascript'> " +
        "var intervalId = null; " +
        "function RenderCharts(){ " +
        "FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript'); " +
        "$('#divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv').empty(); " +
        "$('#divParcGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv').empty(); " +
        "updateFusionChart(\"divActualYearGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv\", \"" + actualXml + "\", \"430px\", \"430px\", \"/CTWebCharts/V3/StackedColumn3DLine.swf\", \"divActualYearGraph\");" +
        "updateFusionChart(\"divParcGraph_Control_ChartDivDiv\", \"" + parcXml + "\", \"430px\", \"430px\", \"/CTWebCharts/V3/StackedColumn3DLine.swf\", \"divParcGraph\");" +
        "intervalId = setInterval(HaveIRenderedYet, 3000);" +
        "} " +
        "" +
        "function HaveIRenderedYet(){" +
        "if($('#divParcGraphLoaded').val()=='true'&&$('#divActualYearGraphLoaded').val()=='true'){" +
        "" +
        "window.print();" +
        "setTimeout(function () { "+
        "window.close();"+
        "}, 10); " +
        "clearInterval(intervalId);" +
        "} "+
        "} " +
        "" +
        "function FC_Rendered(DOMId) { " +
        "$(\"#\" + DOMId.split(\"_\")[0] + \"Loaded\").val('true'); " +
        "}" +
        "<\/script>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body onload='RenderCharts();'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='divActualYearGraphLoaded' name='actualYearGraphLoaded' value='false' />" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='divParcGraphLoaded' name='parcGraphLoaded' value='false' />" +
        "<input type='hidden' id='hdnLoadedGraphs' name='loadedGraphs' value='0' />" +
        $("#ReportDataContainer").html() +
        "</body>");

    drill.document.close();

}

var drill = null;
```